# Regex to get particular block inside braces

Tags: python, regex

String:
`abc-1/1/0/E1 : name=abc-1/1/0/E1, kl/admin=up,kl/admin=up, kl/admin=[1, 2, 3]`

I need to match:
`kl/admin=[1, 2, 3]`

I have used `,.*?=\[.*\]`

But it is not working.

Comment: Would the portion of interest always be at the end of the string? Also, could there be whitespaces in the string of interest? Your title also says *"Regex to get particular block **inside** braces"*. Yet you are also interested in parts outside the braces? Could you clarify a bit more on expected return and the pattern your string would have.

Comment: @JvdV The combination can be present anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[^\s,=]+=\[[^][]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ErWeJp/1)

**Details**

- `[^\s,=]+` - one or more chars other than a comma, whitespace or `=`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, then any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/QTjNAT):

```
import re
rx = r"[^\s,=]+=\[[^][]*]"
s = "abc-1/1/0/E1 : name=abc-1/1/0/E1, kl/admin=up,kl/admin=up, kl/admin=[1, 2, 3]"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
  print( m.group() ) # => kl/admin=[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code:

```
import re
regexExp = r"kl\/admin=(\[.*\]).*"
string = "abc-1/1/0/E1 : name=abc-1/1/0/E1, kl/admin=up,kl/admin=up, kl/admin=[1, 2, 3]"
matchValues = re.findall(regexExp, string)
if matchValues:
  print(matchValues)
```

Please check [online](https://onlinegdb.com/BJKO3l7gv)